# Updating apps installed via ubuntu make

Tags: intellij, ubuntu-make

I installed Intellij Idea Ultimate 2016.2 via Ubuntu Make. How can i upgrade to the latest version "2016.4" via Ubuntu Make?

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done using umake, here's a link to the closed github issue [How to update installed software?#122](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/122).
As mentionned you only need to remove the package and reinstall it like this.

```
umake --remove ide idea && umake ide idea
```

I posted a way to update all your umake packages at once in this self-aswered question [How to update all your ubuntu-make packages?](https://askubuntu.com/a/845894/160395)

Comment: intellij handles all these minor 2016.* by itself so i haven't had to reinstall and install it again. When the 2017 gets released then i can know the answer of my question or validate yours.