# How to update all your ubuntu-make packages?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-make

Currently you can't update packages with umake. Here's a link to the closed github issue How to update installed software?#122. As mentionned you only need to remove the package and reinstall it like this.

```
umake --remove <type> <package> && umake <type> <package>
```

For example, if you know that idea shoul be reinstalled, type:

```
umake --remove ide idea && umake ide idea
```

So I was lookong for a solution to update all my umake packages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have choosed default installation path, all packages are installed in `$HOME/.local/share/umake/`

So you can list them and update them like this:

```
for path in $(ls -d $HOME/.local/share/umake/**/*/); do
    package=$(basename ${path});
    type=$(basename $(dirname ${path}));
    echo "Reinstalling ${package} of ${type}";
    umake --remove $type $package && umake $type $package;
done
```

Comment: so is there is no "umake upgrade" command to update all apps installed from umake?